# C# instantiating class object & adding to List

Tags: c#

How can I create new instance of Country which uses 3 variables firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam for its constructor and add to a List countryList?

The 3 variables are being read from .txt and split on the , 
Afghanistan,Kabul,30419928
Albania,Tirana,2821977

My 3 split variables firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam contain the right information. I think I am making a syntax mistake when I add to the countryList because debug mode stepping through the variables load the right info but when I try a foreach on the countryList I get the output "countries.country".

```
    List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] criteria = line.Split(',');

            string firstParam = "";
            string secondParam = "";
            int thirdParam = 1;

            firstParam = criteria[0];
            secondParam = criteria[1];
            thirdParam = Convert.ToInt32(criteria[2]);

            countryList.Add(new Country(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam));


        }
```

I ran out of ideas and not sure what else to try I am trying to learn more about composition but hoping someone can nudge me along.
thank you.

Comment: Please show us the code you use to get the output (the foreach on the countryList).

Comment: show the code that prints the output

Comment: Yep, aside from not doing any validation on the input, that code looks ok, except you can combine the declaration and instantiation of the three param variables. No need to assign them to default values when you're just reassigning them again in the next few lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose the value for debugging, you should use this way 'Override ToString()' or 'DebuggerDisplayAttribute'.

```
 //DebuggerDisplayAttribute
[DebuggerDisplay("Value = {Display}")]
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }    

    public string Display
    {
        get => $"{Name}, {City}";
    }

    //Override ToString()
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}, {City}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ToString()` just return `Display`?

Comment: Yes, of course.
I just created an example that says you can use either one.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to verify your code is working the way you want it to:

```
List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] criteria = line.Split(',');

    countryList.Add(new Country(criteria[0],
                                criteria[1],
                                Convert.ToInt32(criteria[2]))
}

Console.WriteLine($"Countries in countryList: {countryList.Count}.");

foreach ( Country country in countryList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {country.Name}, Capital: {country.Capital}, Population: {country.Population}.");
}
```

You may need to insert your own names for the fields of your Country class instead of Name, Capital, and Population.

Comment: to print the countryList I used
`code
foreach (Country singleCountry in countryList) <br/>
            {</br>
                Console.WriteLine(singleCountry.Name);<br/>
                // I tried without the .Name<br/>
                // Console.WriteLine(singleCountry);  <br/>
            }`

Comment: if i do Console.WriteLine(firstParam); 

I can see of the variables correctly so the problem is adding to the list or how I print out the list.

I will try the overload method suggested and then reread all comments :D

Comment: When i do a for each to view what is inside my countryList the output just displays "countries.country" for each entry. 
If i do foreach and use .Name i get a blank result. No errors just blank console.
`code foreach (Country item in countryList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            } <br/>`

Comment: why wont line breaks work I am ending line with 2 spaces and i tried the <br/>

Comment: I think i have better question. Instead of trying to sole entire thing can someone please tell me the syntax how to Add a new instance of a class to a list?

 I know the 3 variables firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam all contain the right info.<br>

So the problem is the way i am adding the instantiated object to a list.

Comment: You are instantiating the objects correctly and adding them to the list correctly. What do you want to do with the List that you are having a problem with?